# How to add variable and do loop in CSS

Tags: css, variables

Is it possible to add variable and do loop in css like php:

```
for($a=6; $a<9; $a++) { "#divShow"+$a }
```

So, the result will be:

```
#divShow6 #divShow7 #divShow8
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are no 'variables' or 'loops' in CSS. It is not a Turing-complete language. This is what CSS classes are for, so you don't have to generate IDs.

Comment: You would use JavaScript to do this type of processing.

Comment: Or PHP, or Perl, or Python, or any number of other actual languages which may or may not begin with 'P'.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have loops in CSS, but if you want to match all the tags with an id that starts with `divShow` you can use (example http://jsfiddle.net/diegof79/mUGsj/):

```
div[id^="divShow"]
```

But I'll recommend to use a class instead.

Also your question shows a match of childrens: `divShow8` inside a `divShow7`. You don't need that kind of selector, because probably the problem can be resolved in another way (by using classes or different id).

Take a look to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp maybe it gives you other ideas.